# About the parameters passed to the ctor of `std::thread`

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

As this code snippet does not compile, I understand that the `std::thread` need `callable&&` other than `callable&`.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <thread>
    #include <future>
    #include <functional>
     
    // unique function to avoid disambiguating the std::pow overload set
    int f(int x, int y) { return std::pow(x,y); }
     
    void task_thread()
    {
        std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> task(f);
        std::future<int> result = task.get_future();
     
        std::thread task_td(task, 2, 10);  //std::move(task) works
        task_td.join();
     
        std::cout << "task_thread:\t" << result.get() << '\n';
    }
     
    int main()
    {
        task_thread();
    }
```

As `std::thread` need `callable&&`, why this code snippet below works?
In this code snippet, `f1` is a normal function, I think it's a `callable&` other than `callable&&`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
 
void f1(int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread 1 executing\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
 
void f2(int& n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << "Thread 2 executing\n";
        ++n;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    }
}
 
class foo
{
public:
    void bar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Thread 3 executing\n";
            ++n;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    int n = 0;
};
 
class baz
{
public:
    void operator()()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            std::cout << "Thread 4 executing\n";
            ++n;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    int n = 0;
};
 
int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    foo f;
    baz b;
    std::thread t1; // t1 is not a thread
    std::thread t2(f1, n + 1); // pass by value
    std::thread t3(f2, std::ref(n)); // pass by reference
    std::thread t4(std::move(t3)); // t4 is now running f2(). t3 is no longer a thread
    std::thread t5(&foo::bar, &f); // t5 runs foo::bar() on object f
    std::thread t6(b); // t6 runs baz::operator() on a copy of object b
    t2.join();
    t4.join();
    t5.join();
    t6.join();
    std::cout << "Final value of n is " << n << '\n';
    std::cout << "Final value of f.n (foo::n) is " << f.n << '\n';
    std::cout << "Final value of b.n (baz::n) is " << b.n << '\n';
}
```

Comment: std::thread does not require callable&&, && here is not r-value reference but is a forwarding reference. I.e. either collable&& or callable copy (f1 is the second case).

Comment: This is not specific to `std::thread`, btw. Also, you have the documentation at cppreference.com, check out the available constructors there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::thread` takes all of the objects it is given (the function to be called and its parameters) by "decay copy". This effectively means that a new object will be created for each parameter given. These objects will be stored by `std::thread` and used when calling your function on the new thread. The new objects will be created via copy if you provide lvalues, or by move if you provide xvalues or prvalues.

This means that, by default, `std::thread` *will not* reference variables outside of the constructor call itself. This also means that it requires explicit effort (`std::ref` or similar) to access an object through a parameter which is not owned by the thread being invoked.

`packaged_task` is a move-only type. The compilation failed because you did not invoke `std::move` on it, so decay-copy attempted to copy the type. Since it's move-only, compilation failed. But that is a property of `packaged_task`, not of `std::thread`.

Comment: I see, thank you for your detailed explanation. Only one question left, what's `decay copy`?

Comment: @John: The rest of the paragraph describes what it means.